# how to Preview /add thumbnail image to AllVideos plugin in joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

So, I've browsed the forum trying to find an answer to how to add a preview image to videos (so the video player doesn't just display a black screen before you press "play") and I came across this:

---

"This example of embedding a local FLV video with a preview image uses the following tag:

{flv img="segeln-preview.jpg" showstop="true"}Segeln-20070428-Start{/flv}The video file can be downloaded here. The preview image is located in images/stories and can be downloaded here."

---

I tried this and it doesn't work. If I add the code like this...
{flv}myvideonamehere{/flv}
...the video works great, but there is no preview image.

If i create a shot of the video, and place it in the images/stories folder (btw, my videos are in images/stories/videos) and then add this code...
{flv img="myvideonamehere.jpg" showstop="true"}myvideonamehere{/flv}
...the the video player doesn't appear on the front end, but rather the code itself shows where the video player should be, which is basically means that the plugin doesn't understand that code, so it treats it as normal text in an article.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution: the image must have the same name as the video and be in the same folder. (note the size!)