# How to put a preview image in All Videos plugin for K2 Item

Tags: video, joomla, k2

I'm using K2 for my joomla website, and I embeded an internal video stored in my server in a K2 article. For embeding videos in K2 articles I'm using AllVideos Joomla plugin but I wan't to show a preview image in the video container but this plugin apparently has no such option. So how can I show a preview image of my video?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to Preview /add thumbnail image to AllVideos plugin in joomla](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556797/how-to-preview-add-thumbnail-image-to-allvideos-plugin-in-joomla)

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30124355/5285463 basically the image must have the same name as the video and be in the same folder